# What could cause intermittent failures where Capybara cannot find page elements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, capybara, github-actions

My Rails project is hitting a number of intermittent Cucumber test failures caused by Capybara failing to find an element on a page to interact with. For example:

```
Unable to find button "Delete pupil" that is not disabled (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

These failures are much more common when running in CI in GitHub Actions and I had thought they were caused by Capybara not waiting long enough for the page to render (which presumably takes longer on their servers than locally). However I have refactored all code to use finders (the above failure runs `find_button("Delete pupil").click`), which according to the documentation will wait for the element to appear, but am still getting these intermittent failures.

What else could be causing them?

Answer (score 0):

Most of Capybaras methods will wait for elements to exist but only up to `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` seconds.  That number defaults to 2. So, by default, most find and interaction methods (that take a selector or locator) will wait up to 2 seconds for the element to appear.

```
find_button("Delete pupil") # will wait up to 2 seconds for a matching button

click_button("Delete pupil") # will wait up to 2 seconds for a matching button to appear and click it if it does appear.
```

If 2 seconds is not long enough you can increase that time

```
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5 # finders/action will wait up to 5 seconds for the element to appear
```

or you can do it on a one-time basis by passing the `wait` option to finders/actions

```
click_button("Delete pupil", wait: 5) # will wait for up to 5 seconds for the element to appear for only this call
```